# Get data-* value on button click

Tags: jquery

I have this button

```
<button type="button" class="breakbtn btn btn-danger btn-cons btn-primary btn-block m-t-5" data-amounts="'+amounts+'" id="'+ti+'">Break</button>
```

and i am getting the value of id and data-amounts field after i click the button.

I can get the id using this code

```
var arr = event.target.id;
```

but this does not give the value

```
var initial = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-amounts');
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8oLrxort/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either:

```
var initial = event.target.getAttribute('data-amounts');
```

Or:

```
var initial = event.target.dataset.amounts;
```

```js
function withDataset(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.amounts)
}

function withGetAttribute(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-amounts'));
}

var one = document.getElementById('one'),
  two = document.getElementById('two');

one.addEventListener('click', withDataset);
two.addEventListener('click', withGetAttribute);
```

```html
<button id="one" data-amounts="20">button 1</button>
<button id="two" data-amounts="400">button 2</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/21m3kzyd/).

Reference:

- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dataset` property to get `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) value

```
var initial = event.target.dataset.amounts;
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var arr = event.target.id;
  var id = arr;
  var initial = event.target.dataset.amounts;
  alert(arr);
  alert(initial);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="breakbtn btn btn-danger btn-cons btn-primary btn-block m-t-5" data-amounts="200" id="10">Break</button>
```